# Chrome extension V3 - continue process when popup closes

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension

There are other similar questions on StackOverflow, but I think I have a unique case.

I'm creating a Chrome extension with React. The extension requests data from a server and fills in a forms on a specific website. The extension can move between views by clicking buttons. The process can take a few minutes. I would like the user to be able to use other browser tabs/windows while the process is running, but currently if the user clicks away the popup closes and the process is killed.

Currently, it all works using React. When agent presses a button, a correct **Executor** class is found, and a method is called on it. But when the user clicks away, the popup closes and the process is killed. I found a tip that using a chrome/window listener, the extension should stay/become active if the listener is used.

I tried putting the executor call inside a service worker. However, the Executor uses a library that internally needs the window object and as background process cannot access it, I get an error (window is not defined).

Then I tried to use a content-script to call the executor. When the process tries to click a button, it calls a clicker script using `chrome.scripting.executeScript`. Content-scripts cannot use the scripting API and I again get an error (executeScript is not a function).

How could I execute the process so that it isn't killed when the popup is closed?

**Edit:**
Window property in the library

```
declare global {
  interface Window {
    __SOMETHING__?: boolean;
  }
}
```

Error in the library is thrown on a line

```
if (!window.__SOMETHING__) {
```

Comment: What `window` properties does it use? If none, you can simply add `self.window = self` to the service worker.

Comment: I added `self.window = self` to the file. I had to disable an inspection, but anyways it did not seem to do anything.

Comment: This particular check would work with self.window patch, assuming you apply it before the code runs. If there's more, you should debug it and find what else it needs, then add similar patches.

Comment: Adding `self.window = self` to the file which configures the library where the error originates, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property window of #<Window> which has only a getter`

Comment: Since there's no such error for service worker, I guess you see this error when the code runs in a tab/popup. You can add a check like `if (!self.window) self.window = self`. Also note that if the library is imported via a static `import` statement, your code may run too late. In that case you need to use a separate js file that sets self.window and import it before the library.

Comment: That did help! But now I get `Uncaught ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined` in the same library

Comment: Well, like I said, investigate how the library uses window-specific stuff. In this case, see if its use of localStorage is meaningful. If yes, you can't use it in a service worker and you'll have to split the library into an [offscreen document](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/offscreen/). If no, you can write a trivial patch for localStorage.